# How do I make a file usable by my app but not viewable in the browser?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a file in my app that's used by the app to determined settings such as max upload size, whether users can sign up or not ect. And I need it in the app director ao that people can change their local config. But unfortunately you can go /config/local.json and download it.
I did think about making /config/ rewrite to a PHP page but that's kinda long but I may yet have to do that.

I am running PHP as an Apache module. Is there a way I can do this with .htaccess or something?

Comment: I'm guessing the local.json config is parsed with Javascript? I don't believe Apache has a way to restrict access to files for a user while allowing PHP to still interact with them (unless the file is outside of the root directory). If you want to leave the file in the root your best bet will probably be setting up the local.json as a php page with a JSON header so that you can include some php logic to restrict access.

Comment: Just use a file extension that can't be downloaded as-is, such as `config.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could be acceptable in the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
    php_value post_max_size 20M
    php_value max_execution_time 200
    php_value max_input_time 200
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can keep the file outside the document root (one directory up from the base directory where you hold your site) and access that file from the script.

You can edit document root in your apache configuration file.

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` for *nix Environments

Comment: It needs to be shipped with the app and easy for the person to modify.

Comment: Maybe there is a Linux file setting that will allow it to be read by the app but no a user?